# How to remove key from object before a new is set?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

New key is assigned like this, but old key need to remove, how can I do in a compact way without interfering with assigning?

```js
{Object.entries(environments).map(([k, v]) => (

<input
  type="text"
  className="input-text border border-radius lightgray-background"
  value={k}
  onChange={(e) => {
    setEnvironments({
      ...environments,
      [e.target.value]: v,
    });
  }}
/>

)}
```

Comment: I don't see any reference to the word `key` anywhere in your code (maybe k). If this is the case, you can keep the keys in a state variable, or update the list of inputs when a useEffect() triggers.

Comment: In the example you've shown (of a [controlled input](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)), the DOM element's `value` will never update (unless there's some other logic you've not shown which updates `k` as a side effect of calling `setEnvironments`).

Comment: I thought `e.target.value` will have the new value, user set in the textfield

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the old key ?

Comment: Also, how is `v` created? How is each input created? You need to provide a [mre]. At any rate, it's likely that you're not defining unique keys for each item, which is (1) currently a bug in your code (see [Lists and keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)), and (2) likely the solution to whatever problem you're asking about.

Comment: Given that an object is an unordered collection, this looks like a bad idea; your inputs will jump around; and should you ever enter the same value in two of them, they'll automatically get coalesced into a single input field. Before asking about removing the old key, please describe what your actual goal is.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you render a list in React, you must provide a stable (deterministic) value for the `key` attribute of each item. Not doing so is a bug because — otherwise — React has no idea which data belongs with which item in the series.

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity.

This behavior is covered in detail in the documentation section titled [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

If you need to manage a collection of items with independently editable keys and values — and **especially** if it's a possibility for the collection's keys to contain duplicates (as is suggested in your question code) — then the keys in the collection are not necessarily unique identifiers, and are not appropriate for use as *React keys* in a list of rendered nodes.

You can use a unique string (e.g. a UUIDv4 generated from [`Crypto.randomUUID()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/randomUUID)) as the actual, internal and unique key for each of your key-value entries.

In context of the information above, a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is probably a better data structure for your environment data: not only can you store a key and value as a tuple in each entry — a `Map` also gives you stronger control over the order of its entries: unlike an object, whose keys are deterministically ordered with some restrictions (see [Does JavaScript guarantee object property order?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5525795/438273)), a Map's entries are always ordered according to insertion.

Below I've created a self-contained example of using a `Map` as state to store a collection of editable key-value entries, including a component for visualizing the state.

> Select "Full page" after running the code snippet to get an expanded viewport for the demo.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; } body { font-family: sans-serif; } button, input[type="text"] { font-size: 1rem; padding: 0.5rem; } .entry-list { list-style: none; padding: 0; } .entry-row { display: flex; gap: 0.5rem; } pre.visual { background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 50%, 0.1); font-size: 1rem; padding: 1rem; } pre.visual > code { font-family: monospace; line-height: 1.5; }
```

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@babel/standalone@7.20.6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="env,react">

const {useCallback, useState} = React;

function VisualizeState ({serializable}) {
  return (
    <pre className="visual">
      <code>{JSON.stringify(serializable, null, 2)}</code>
    </pre>
  );
}

function TextInput ({placeholder, value, setValue}) {
  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      onChange={ev => setValue(ev.target.value)}
      {...{placeholder, value}}
    />
  );
}

// The default values for a new key-value entry in the environment:
const createDefaultEnvEntry = () => ['', ''];

function App () {
  const [environmentMap, setEnvironmentMap] = useState(new Map());

  const setEnvKey = useCallback(
    (uuid, key) => setEnvironmentMap(m => {
      const map = new Map([...m.entries()]);
      const entry = map.get(uuid) ?? createDefaultEnvEntry();
      entry[0] = key;
      map.set(uuid, entry);
      return map;
    }),
    [setEnvironmentMap],
  );

  const setEnvValue = useCallback(
    (uuid, value) => setEnvironmentMap(m => {
      const map = new Map([...m.entries()]);
      const entry = map.get(uuid) ?? createDefaultEnvEntry();
      entry[1] = value;
      map.set(uuid, entry);
      return map;
    }),
    [setEnvironmentMap],
  );

  const createEnvEntry = useCallback(
    () => setEnvironmentMap(m => new Map([
      ...m.entries(),
      [crypto.randomUUID(), createDefaultEnvEntry()],
    ])),
    [setEnvironmentMap],
  );

  const deleteEnvEntry = useCallback(
    (uuid) => setEnvironmentMap(m => {
      const map = new Map([...m.entries()]);
      map.delete(uuid);
      return map;
    }),
    [setEnvironmentMap],
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="entry-list">
        {
          [...environmentMap.entries()].map(([uuid, [key, value]]) => (
            // Note the use of the "key" attribute with the mapped node child:
            <li className="entry-row" key={uuid}>
              <TextInput
                placeholder="key"
                value={key}
                setValue={key => setEnvKey(uuid, key)}
              />
              <TextInput
                placeholder="value"
                value={value}
                setValue={value => setEnvValue(uuid, value)}
              />
              <button onClick={() => deleteEnvEntry(uuid)}>Delete entry</button>
            </li>
          ))
        }
      </ul>
      <button onClick={() => createEnvEntry()}>Create new entry</button>
      <div>
        <p>Visulization of state:</p>
        <VisualizeState
          serializable={Object.fromEntries([...environmentMap.entries()])}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const reactRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

reactRoot.render(<App />);

</script>
```

Comment: "*if it's a possibility for the collection's keys to contain duplicates (as is suggested in your question code)*" - I don't see that, an object like `environments` cannot have duplicate property names.

Comment: "*a `Map` also gives you complete control over the order of its entries*" - no it doesn't. It just has different deterministic rules for iterating its entries, but - just like an object - it still represents an unordered collection.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74601362/how-to-remove-key-from-object-before-a-new-is-set/74603559?noredirect=1#comment131686105_74603559) @Bergi "_an object like `environments` cannot have duplicate property names_" Of course that's true. However, the OP hasn't provided a [mre], so we can't say for sure what the intent actually is...

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74601362/how-to-remove-key-from-object-before-a-new-is-set/74603559?noredirect=1#comment131686124_74603559) @Bergi "_it still represents an unordered collection_": This is not correct: the order of a map's entries is always that of insertion — it is guaranteed. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/keyed-collections.html#sec-map-objects) for details.

Comment: Yes, same as for object properties (mod integer-like properties). But a consistent guaranteed iteration order doesn't make the collection ordered, you cannot reorder or sort the entries, that is not what it is meant to represent.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74601362/how-to-remove-key-from-object-before-a-new-is-set/74603559?noredirect=1#comment131686698_74603559) I think it was just a semantic misunderstanding: I didn't claim sortability — if that's what you interpreted, how can I revise the phrasing to more clearly represent [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74601362/how-to-remove-key-from-object-before-a-new-is-set/74603559?noredirect=1#comment131686619_74603559)?

Comment: I'd remove the part about "*complete control over the order of its entries*". But also I'm not certain why you brought this up at all, I don't see how your answer works different than if done with an object. Given the OPs question is unclear without knowing their actual intentions, I wouldn't even claim that "*a `Map` is probably a better data structure for your environment data*". It might be, but I couldn't tell.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74601362/how-to-remove-key-from-object-before-a-new-is-set/74603559?noredirect=1#comment131686877_74603559) @Bergi Thanks, I'll revise that phrase. "_I don't see how your answer works different than if done with an object._" I chose UUIDs, but didn't assume that the OP would. Maps allow for non-string keys as well (another bonus) — and if the OP chose some number-like strings mixed with other strings, then the ES2015 object key sorting logic might cause problems — whereas a Map wouldn't be affected by that.

Comment: Yeah, but when using uuids for the keys, an object would've worked just as well.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74601362/how-to-remove-key-from-object-before-a-new-is-set/74603559?noredirect=1#comment131686997_74603559) @Bergi I generally try to keep the [robustness principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) in mind when writing code examples — especially on SO where things are often not communicated with maximal clarity.